# Changing the soft keyboard height

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I need to reduce the size of android soft keyboard for landscape mode.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       /* MyKeyboard myKeyboard = new MyKeyboard(this,);   
        adjustKeyboardKeyHeight(myKeyboard,100);*/


    }

    private void adjustKeyboardKeyHeight (MyKeyboard keyboard, int newKeyHeight) {
        int oldKeyHeight = keyboard.getKeyHeight();
        int verticalGap = keyboard.getVerticalGap();
        int rows = 0;
        for (Keyboard.Key key : keyboard.getKeys()) {
            key.height = newKeyHeight;
            int row = (key.y + verticalGap) / (oldKeyHeight + verticalGap);
            key.y = row * newKeyHeight + (row - 1) * verticalGap;
            rows = Math.max(rows, row + 1);
        }
        keyboard.setHeight(rows * newKeyHeight + (rows - 1) * verticalGap);
    }

    private static class MyKeyboard extends Keyboard {
        private int height;
        MyKeyboard (Context context, int xmlLayoutResId) {
            super(context, xmlLayoutResId);
            height = super.getHeight();
        }
        @Override public int getKeyHeight() {
            return super.getKeyHeight();
        }
        @Override public int getVerticalGap() {
            return super.getVerticalGap();
        }
        public void setHeight (int newHeight) {
            height = newHeight;
        }
        @Override public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a doubt on what to pass for xmlLayoutResId
`MyKeyboard myKeyboard = new MyKeyboard(this,);`   //In this line I need to 
know what to pass for that xmlLayoutResId

Comment: The keyboard is a completely separate app. You have no control over its layout.

Comment: @MikeM. You mean the user have to change the soft keyboard size manually in the device?

Comment: If the keyboard app offers such a setting, yes, that's what they'd have to do.

Comment: The only thing you can do is to create a soft keyboard app, and let the user choose what you created. Then, since it is your app as well, you can set the height of the soft keyboard.